# Stop popup from opening

Tags: android, popup, conditional-statements

I have a  pop up that appears on screen every x times but I want that after the user press the `Send Button`  I want that the pop up to stop appearing after x openings 
Here is my code for the popup :

```
 private void dialog() {
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_up);
    editTextEmailValue = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextMessageValue = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);
    editTextNumeValue = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextNume);
    Button btnSend = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
    Button btnClose = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.close);

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (check() == 0) {
                sendMail();
                myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    myDialog.setCancelable(false);
    myDialog.show();
}
```

Here is how I count the app opening :

```
//this in in onCreate method
prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();

    totalCount = prefs.getInt("counter", 0);
    totalCount++;
    editor.putInt("counter", totalCount);
    editor.commit();


    if (totalCount % 2 == 0) {
        dialog();
    }
```

I tried to put a condition in  `if(totalCount % 2 == 0 && stop == 1)` and i put  `stop = 0` in  `btnSend.onClickListener()` like this:

```
 btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (check() == 0) {
                sendMail();
                myDialog.dismiss();
                stop = 0; //Note that the stop variable is public
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code, the dialog will open one time in two because each time you increment totalCount and after you check totalCount modulo 2

first opening totalCount = 1 (dialog opened)

second opening totalCount = 2 (dialog still closed)

third opening totalCount = 3 (dialog opened)

Comment: I know but i want after i press the send button to stop the counting for totalCount or somehow to block the count

Comment: You've done the right thing :) . Just stop to increment totalCount, or use a boolean instead of totalCount, or use the condition if (totalCount > 1). And if user click on send button, add a value in your prefs

Comment: i put like this when i press the button totalCount = -1; and i put the condition if (.. && totalCount >0) but it still doesent work